# Connection Refused: cannot access RabbitMQ Docker container from NodeJS Docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, rabbitmq

I am having trouble connecting a Docker container running NodeJS to another docker container running RabbitMQ.

I googled and looked around but did not see anything specifically for issue I am running into. I am not sure if this something silly I am missing or something else.

To connect from NodeJS, first I tried just using the [ampqlib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/amqplib) library. And that would give me a connection refused from NodeJS. So then I tried looking for other alternatives and found [Rascal](https://github.com/guidesmiths/rascal). It is a wrapper around `ampqlib`. I see same error for both:

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 192.XXX.XXX.X:5672
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1195:16) {
  errno: -111,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '192.XXX.XXX.X',
  port: 5672,
  broker: Symbol()
}
```

The connection string from NodeJS used to connect:

`amqp://${process.env.RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER}:${process.env.RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS}@${process.env.RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_HOST}:${process.env.RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PORT}`;`

The `HOST` for this is `RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_HOST=rabbitmq` as what I have set in the `docker-compose` below.

These are pulled in from a `.env` file that I checked and the NodeJS app can read them fine.

Things I have tested so far:

1. I can see the rabbitmq container running and ready for connections on port `5672`:

```
2022-05-27 15:16:06.422648+00:00 [info] <0.680.0> Ready to start client connection listeners
2022-05-27 15:16:06.429403+00:00 [info] <0.825.0> started TCP listener on [::]:5672
 completed with 4 plugins.
2022-05-27 15:16:06.627770+00:00 [info] <0.680.0> Server startup complete; 4 plugins started.
2022-05-27 15:16:06.627770+00:00 [info] <0.680.0>  * rabbitmq_prometheus
2022-05-27 15:16:06.627770+00:00 [info] <0.680.0>  * rabbitmq_management
2022-05-27 15:16:06.627770+00:00 [info] <0.680.0>  * rabbitmq_web_dispatch
2022-05-27 15:16:06.627770+00:00 [info] <0.680.0>  * rabbitmq_management_agent
```

2. I can access the RabbitMQ management UI through web browser on port `15672` using the custom user/pass I set through env variables. I had to configure the NGINX reverse proxy but it worked.
3. The `docker-compose` for relevant pieces looks like this:

```
  #################
  ### rabbit mq ###
  #################
  rabbitmq:
    hostname: rabbitmq
    container_name: rabbitmq
    image: rabbitmq:management
    environment:
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER: ${RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER}
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS: ${RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS}
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_HOST: ${RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_HOST}
    ports:
      # AMQP protocol port
      - '5672:5672'
      # HTTP management UI
      - '15672:15672'

  ######################
  ### nodejs-client ####
  ######################
  api-client:
    container_name: api-client
    restart: unless-stopped
    build: ./packages/market/api-client
    env_file:
      - ./packages/market/api-client/.env
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq
      - api
    links:
      - rabbitmq
      - api
```

4. Making sure the username/password did not have any strange characters that could break the string, so just using things like test:test but still no luck.

If anyone has run into this before or has any ideas or suggestions I would greatly appreciate as I am stumped! Thank you

5. I am not configuring any Docker network other than the default one. When I do `docker network inspect app_default` I can see the `rabbitmq` and `api-client` containers listed for this network.

Comment: The `links:` block is obsolete and unnecessary, and I've suspected it in some similar SO questions.  Does removing it help at all?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I did not know about the `links` deprecation so I removed the `links` and app is working fine.

I figured out the issue, it is that everything is starting together here and the NodeJS app is running before RabbitMQ has started. So, I put a timeout to wait a couple of minutes and it worked. I do not know of a better way to handle that, maybe a custom bash script to wait to load the NodeJS app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out the issue: I needed to have the NodeJS app wait some time before trying to connect to RabbitMQ container. I put a `setTimeout` to wait for a couple of minutes and it was able to successfully connect.

I do not know of a better way to wait. I have tried `wait-for-it` before, maybe I will write a custom bash script that is specific to my setup to only start the NodeJS container after some time has passed.